# What does "a constant drip-drip of information" mean?

Tags: idiom-meaning

What is the meaning of "a constant drip-drip of information" in this sentence?

> I have **a constant drip-drip of information** from any of the 750 online friends and followers that I associate with.

Comment: I'm more used to [*the constant **drip-feed** of information*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22constant+drip-feed+of+information%22) (26 hits in Google Books), rather than [*constant drip drip of information*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22constant+drip+drip+of+information%22) (just 2 hits). Without the ***of information*** qualifier, ***drip-drip*** is far more common, but imho that's just because it's often used ***literally*** (or metaphorically of "[Chinese] water torture" which is irrelevant to / incompatible with the "information" context).

Comment: @FF JL would probably say that this is the well-known trickle metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

The Cambridge Dictionary [drip, drip](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/drip-drip-drip) defines this as mainly British and applying to something bad, but it is also AmE and can be applied, e.g., to the slow revelation of clues in a detective story.

> drip, drip(, drip) mainly UK ​ used to describe a process in which
>   something bad happens very slowly: the steady drip, drip, drip with
>   which small, independently owned businesses are disappearing

See also Wikipedia on Chinese water torture:

> Chinese water torture is a process in which water is slowly dripped
>   onto a person's forehead, allegedly driving the restrained victim
>   insane. This form of torture was first described under a different
>   name by Hippolytus de Marsiliis in Italy in the 15th or 16th century.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted -- looks good to me. // Not sure how the water torture paragraph helps.  The Cambridge definition and example do the trick by themselves, in my opinion.

Comment: +1 As for the Chinese water torture, one would be driven mad If there was no way to tune out in the situation the OP describes.

Answer (score 0):

Drip... Drip, is not always bad it just means the thing happens in small chunks over a period of time, rather than all at the same time.

In this case I think it means that the person is getting fed-up (bored / annoyed) with the constant stream of potentially 750 messages per day from their contacts.  Most importantly, the implication is that the messages arrive one at a time, rather than in a single daily down-load, which makes them a constant distraction or irritation:

[Chinese Water Torture - where the victim was tormented / driven mad by the constant 'drip... drip.... drip' of water from a small hole in a bucket suspended above their forehead, the drips continuing until they provided the information required]

Answer (score 0):

It's the middle of the night and you're trying to sleep.  But the faucet in the bathroom sink is a little flaky, and so you hear a constant "drip ... drip ... drip".

It's seeming trivial, but it will not allow you to put your mind on something else and drift off.

So you lay there all night, and somehow each drip becomes louder than the last -- "drip ... *drip* ... *DRIP* ... ***DRIP***".

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> ***stream***
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stream):
>
>   1
>     a body of running water (such as a river or creek)
>   2d
>     digital data … that is continuously delivered
>
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/stream):
>
>   2
>     A continuous flow of liquid, air, or gas.
>   3
>     A continuous flow of data …
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stream):
>
>   1.
>     a.
>       A flow of water in a channel or bed,
>         as a brook, rivulet, or small river.
>     b.
>       A steady current in such a flow of water.
>   7.
>     A steady flow of data.
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/stream_1):
>
>   2
>     a continuous flow of people or things
>     a.
>       a continuous flow of liquid or gas

A “**stream** of information” is a steady, continuous flow of information. 
The writer is playing off the water/liquid definition of ***stream***
to make an analogy; “a constant **drip-drip** of information”
is a flow of information, but in small amounts, arriving intermittently.